# Excel Hyperlink To Another Hyperlink On Another Sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, hyperlink

Based upon a value in cell E138 on Sheet 1, I am trying to look up that value in a table on Sheet 2 and open the corresponding Hyperlink in the 7th column over which is a link to Sheet 3, Sheet 4 etc.

If the Hyperlink on Sheet 2 is a web address, it works great with this code:

```
=IF(E138="","",HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP(E138,'Sheet 2'!C5:I10,7,0),"CLICK HERE FOR DATASHEET"))
```

But if I change the Hyperlinks on Sheet 2 from a web address to go to a different Sheet (ie Sheet 3) it does not work.  With this code I get a Reference Isn't Valid Error.

```
=IF(E138="","",HYPERLINK("#(VLOOKUP(E138,'Sheet 2'!C5:I10,7,0))","CLICK HERE FOR DATASHEET"))
```

This gives me a Cannot Open Specified File error:

```
=HYPERLINK((VLOOKUP(E138,'Sheet 2'!C5:I10,7,0)), "CLICK HERE FOR DATASHEET")
```

Sheet 3, Sheet 4 etc contains separate datasheets.
Cell E138 on Sheet 1 contains the datasheet part number that I am looking up on Sheet 2.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

```
=IF(E138="","",HYPERLINK("#(VLOOKUP(E138,'Sheet 2'!C5:I10,7,0))","CLICK HERE FOR DATASHEET"))
```

would need to be

```
=IF(E138 = "","",HYPERLINK("#" & VLOOKUP(E138,'Sheet 2'!C5:I10,7,0),"CLICK HERE FOR DATASHEET"))`
```

Secondly,

```
=HYPERLINK((VLOOKUP(E138,'Sheet 2'!C5:I10,7,0)), "CLICK HERE FOR DATASHEET")
```

should be

```
=HYPERLINK("#" & VLOOKUP(E138,'Sheet 2'!C5:I10,7,0), "CLICK HERE FOR DATASHEET")
```

Third, is your sheet really `Sheet 2` (with a space), or is it the defaut `Sheet2`

Comment: The Sheet 2 versus Sheet2 was a typo. For the sake of the post, I changed the page name for simplicity.

When I use your code:
       =IF(E138 = "","",HYPERLINK("#" & VLOOKUP(E138,'Sheet 2'!C5:I10,7,0),"CLICK HERE FOR DATASHEET"))

I am receiving a "Reference isn't valid" error.

Comment: Then check all your sheet references.  I ran this code, it works once the sheet names are correct

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem without having to change the original formula:

```
=IF(E138="","",HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP(E138,'Sheet 2'!C5:I10,7,0),"CLICK HERE FOR DATASHEET"))
```

On Sheet 2; which has the Table being used to look up the Hyperlink, you have to Edit the Hyperlink (right click>edit hyperlink) and add a # sign in front of the default text that is displayed in the "Text To Display" box.

For example: #'CBO68HP51-100A6'!A1

CBO68HP51-100A6 is the name of my sheet that I am linking to.